# Regex (Kotlin) to match end of sentence periods only and ignore periods in the middle such as abbreviations

Tags: regex, kotlin, regex-negation

I need a regex to find all sentence-ending periods and ignore middle of the sentence periods, such as in abbreviations.
Note: I *understand* that there are many *other* variations, and it may not be possible to account for all of them, so the focus of the question would be : can at least the below sample be solved with a regex?

Suppose I have this text. The regex rule below finds any period matches followed by a white space. But it also matches p.m. and U.S. - how can I ignore periods in a word that a) consists of characters all separated by a period? (such as U.S.) and b) a period preceded by one characters only (such as J.).
This is in Kotlin.

```
        val text = "At 12.51 p.m. local time, J. Knapp, former U.S. Navy,  went out for a walk. Yes he did. And then a Mw6.3 earthquake happened."
        val regexRule = "\\.\\s+"
        val splitText = text.split(regexRule.toRegex())
        val result = splitText.joinToString( separator = ".\n\n")
```

Current result with just that rule:

> At 12.51 p.m.
>
> local time, J.
>
> Knapp, former U.S.
>
> Navy, went out for a walk.
>
> Yes he did.
>
> And then a Mw6.3 earthquake happened.

Comment: Try `"""(?<!\b\p{L})\.(?<!\d.(?=\d))(?!$)\s*"""`. See https://regex101.com/r/EojH9R/1

Comment: @jvDv - unfortunately -  val reg = "(?<!\b.|\\d)\\." - breaks up the text after every single period

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do I need the quotes around? when copy pasted into Android Studio, this becomes val regexRule = "\"\"\"(?<!\\b\\p{L})\\.(?<!\\d.(?=\\d))(?!\$)\"\"\"" and it doesnt do anything

Comment: `val regexRule = """(?<!\b\p{L})\.(?<!\d.(?=\d))(?!$)\s*"""`. Are you really using Kotlin?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it is Kotlin

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i removed the triple quotes and Android studio inserted backslashes and made it val regexRule = "(?<!\\b\\p{L})\\.(?<!\\d.(?=\\d))(?!\$)". This works! amazing, thank you. If you want to provide as an answer, i will accept

Comment: It is just Android Studio quirk. Triple quotes are valid string literal delimiters in Kotlin.

Comment: @JvdV yes, this one works! thank you so much. But I have to accept Wiktor's answer, as he beat you by a few seconds here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right, its an AS quirk. all is good, thanks, answer accepted

Comment: @JvdV if you want you can still provide an answer and the least i can do is upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```kotlin
val regexRule = "(?<!\\b\\p{L})\\.(?<!\\d.(?=\\d))(?!\\s*\$)\\s*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EojH9R/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\b\p{L})` - a negative lookbehind: no single letter preceded with a word boundary is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?<!\d.(?=\d))` - the dot should not be in-between digits
- `(?!\s*$)` - immediately to the right, there should be no any zero or more whitespaces + the end of the string
- `\s*` - any zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned you want to find a pattern that would atleast solve the given sample. Try to match spaces and assert that there is no word-boundary two positions back nor any digit one position back. For example:

```
(?<=(?<!\b.|\d)\.)\s+
```

- `(?<=` - Open a positive lookbehind;

  - `(?<!` - Open a negative lookbehind;

    - `\b.|\d)` - Match a word-boundary followed by a singel char (any) or a digit and close the negative lookbehind;
  - `\.)` - Match a literal dot and close the positive lookbehind;
  - `\s+` - Match 1+ spaces.

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/P8gpNN/1)

---

[Here](https://pl.kotl.in/4IBmUjJjo) is a snippet of code:

```
fun main() {
    val info = "At 12.51 p.m. local time, J. Knapp, former U.S. Navy,  went out for a walk. Yes he did. And then a Mw6.3 earthquake happened."
    val lines = info.split(Regex("(?<=(?<!\\b.|\\d)\\.)\\s+"))
    for (line in lines) {
        println(line)
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
At 12.51 p.m. local time, J. Knapp, former U.S. Navy,  went out for a walk.
Yes he did.
And then a Mw6.3 earthquake happened.
```

But please note that I have no experience with Kotlin.

Comment: It will fail with a text like `The number was 345. And then ....`.